# flex combine 3 different letters

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, letter

I want to match 3 different letters from range [A-E] in flex language, without repeating any of them.

For e.g. ABC, CDE, EAB,

But not AAB or DEE.

I have tried [A|B|C|D|E]{3}, [A?B?C?D?E?]{3}, [A{0,1}-E{0,1}]{3}, but didn't work... Please help!

Comment: So what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried [A|B|C|D|E]{3}, [A?B?C?D?E?]{3}, [A{0,1}-E{0,1}]{3}, but didn't work...

Comment: You should add that to your question not to attract down votes.  Also if there are arrays and `not in` construct supported in flex then you can do match programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in the team and in flex. I added my comment to my question.

Comment: Are you talking about [this flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) or [this flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Flex)?

Comment: I am talking about the lexical analyser.

Comment: What do you want to happen for an input like `AAA` - a different token or an error? How about `ABCABC` - is that two tokens, an error, or one token of a different type? How about `ABCD`?

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/dxJTTk/1/) ?

Comment: @Rahul Flex doesn't negative lookahead. I don't think there are better options than just spelling out all possibilities (at least for the first two characters) or matching all combinations and rejecting the ones with duplicates in the associated action (assuming that fits OP's requirements).

Comment: @sepp2k: I don't know about flex. If you are acquainted with flex then you can suggest blacklisting those strings in a loop check like I mentioned before.

Comment: In case of AAA I would like to have an error. ABCABC or ABCD are also not acceptable. I want to have only 3 unique letters from range [A-E].

Comment: @zooppee You mean you want only three letters in the entire input file? Usually a lexer will produce more than one token. Or do you just mean that there always needs to be some separator between tokens (like `ABC ABC` would be legal and produce 2 tokens (or three if the whitespace is not skipped))?

Comment: Your first question is what I want. To find any combination of 3 from A-E in the input file.

Comment: "To find any combination of 3 from A-E in the input file." But that doesn't sound the same as only allowing three characters in the file. Like to me finding any combination sounds like for the input "ABC BCD", you'd want to find both "ABC" and "BCD" (both of which are combinations of three characters). So is that what you want or do you really want to only allow "ABC" as the entire input and produce an error if there's more than three characters in the file? If that's what you want, I don't really think flex is a good fit.

Comment: You are right, my answer was not clear. The combination of the 3 letters must appear only once.

Answer (score 0):

One way to match three different letters would be to spell out all legal combinations:

```
ABC|ABD|ABE|ACB|ACD|...  printf("Found one: %s\n", yytext);
```

We can shorten this somewhat by using a character class for the third letter:

```
AB[C-E]|AC[BCD]|AD[BCE]|...  printf("Found one: %s\n", yytext);
```

Given that the range is only A-E, this is somewhat feasible, but certainly not pretty.

The alternative would be to match more than is allowed and then reject the illegal combinations in the associated action. That could look like this:

```
[A-E]{3} {
    if (yytext[0] == yytext[1] || yytext[0] == yytext[2] || yytext[1] == yytext[2]) {
        REJECT;
    } else {
        printf("Found one: %s\n", yytext);
    }
}
```

`REJECT` will make it as if the pattern had never matched, so this will behave the same as the previous solutions.

Note that nothing will prevent either of these solutions to match the pattern more than once - that is the way lexers work after all. So an input like `ABCBCD` would produce the following output:

```
Found one: abc
Found one: bcd
```

Since you said in a comment that that's not what you want, you'll need an additional rule that would match `abcbcd` as one token and then produce an error message. If you really want to only allow inputs that consist of only three characters, you could use `.*` as a pattern to match everything that's not 3 non-repeating A-E characters. That seems like a very strange use of flex though.